# What is the difference between Garbage Collection and Reference Counting in Mac OS

Tags: objective-c, garbage-collection, reference-counting

What is the difference between Garbage Collection and Reference Counting in Mac OS X.

Thanks and regards.
Mahadevan S

Comment: In what context ("Mac OS" is not very precise as a context, especially since it has been "Mac OS X" for 8 years or so)? Reference counting is a basic form of Garbage Collection, but if they are used in opposition, Garbage Collection probably means some kind of "Mark and Sweep" algorithm. http://www.brpreiss.com/books/opus5/html/page424.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When using garbage collection you don't have to worry about releasing the memory that you allocate. The garbage collector will do that for you.

You can read more in the [Garbage Collection Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/GarbageCollection/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001223-CJBGIAGF).

Usually you have to tell the compiler with a flag if you want to have garbage collection enabled.

Garbage collection is available on Mac OS X, but not on iOS.

When not using garbage collection, but reference counting, you must follow the [Memory Management Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/MemoryMgmt.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000011i) and make sure that you release all the objects that you own.